# After uploading an incorrect file my HTML file input does not respond when a new file is uploaded even after first being made null

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file-upload, frontend

I upload a file and it is auto submitted. If I upload a file of the wrong file extension it flasesh a warning then the file input is made null so it can take another file. But when I upload a new file the file isn't submitted and nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'transcribeSubmit' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                            {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="transcribe-file" class="transcribe-file-label">Choose audio/video file</label>
    <input id="transcribe-file" name="file" type="file" accept="audio/*, video/*" hidden>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#transcribe-file');
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
        
        console.log(fileInput.value);
        let fileName = event.target.value;
        const fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        const allowedExtensions = ['m4a', 'wav', 'mp3', 'mpeg', 'mp4', 'webm', 'mpga', 'ogg', 'flac'];
        
        if (!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
            const uploadField = document.querySelector('.upload-file-field-transcribe');
            const originalLabelText = uploadField.innerHTML
            uploadField.style.color = '#ad0f0f';
            uploadField.textContent = 'Invalid file type. Please try again';
            
            setTimeout(function() {
                uploadField.style.color = '';
                uploadField.innerHTML = originalLabelText;
            }, 5000);

            // clear the file input field
            fileInput.value = '';
            console.log(fileInput.value);
            return;
        }
        const form = document.querySelector('form');

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                let percentComplete = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                let progressBar = document.getElementById('myBar');
                progressBar.style.width = percentComplete + '%';
                console.log('Upload progress: ' + percentComplete + '%');
            }
        };

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log('Upload complete');
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                // Update the content of the current page with the HTML from the server
                document.body.innerHTML = response.html;
            } else {
                console.error('Upload failed');
            }
        };

        xhr.send(formData);

        // Reset the file input value after form submission
    //event.target.value = null;( I put this code here to test if it will work but it didn't)

    }
});
```

Comment: Try to clone the file input element and replace the original input with the clone. I think this might solve the issue.

Comment: @BugHunter Do you mean like this:

`
```if (!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {

    // ...existing code...

    // Clone the file input element and replace the original with the clone
    const fileInputClone = fileInput.cloneNode(true);
    fileInput.parentNode.replaceChild(fileInputClone, fileInput);

    // U...existing code...

    });

    return;
}```

Comment: Yes, this way user are able to upload file after an invalid file was selected.

Comment: @BugHunter Ok. It still doesn't work. There is no response or error at all.

Comment: if the clone doesnt work then try to create a new file input element and replace the existing one

Comment: @ I found the solution. I  had to change `xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);` to `xhr.open('POST', form.action);`.